# Switch update panel to full postback when specific firefox ver detected

Tags: firefox, updatepanel, postback

I'm facing a problem with firefox versions < 3.6 and I'd like to get a fix for that.
My issue is update_panel related, but I couldn't find any information on similar issues and can't really name the problem as it occurs rarely ( and not on localhost) :

"the updatepanels freezes and doesn't react"

My problem is that I cannot identify the problem and thus would like to switch the updatepanel to work with full postbacks (standard is asnyc) when I detect firefox + ver < 3.6

**My question is basically, how to "disable"/set the updatepanel to do full postbacks only in this case ? Both codebehind and serverside solutions are acccepted**

```
        System.Web.HttpBrowserCapabilities browser = Request.Browser;
        double versionb = 3.5;
        if (browser.Browser == "Firefox" && Convert.ToDouble(browser.Version) <= versionb)
        {

        }
```

Comment: I think some javascript might be conflicting. there be some some error in javascript at some point. try setting alert on different steps to diagnose the issue.

Comment: Firebug used to screw up my ajax stuff on FF.

Comment: I neither have firebug installed, nor do I get errors in my javascript console (Web developer addon). Moreover I don't understand why the error does only occur in 1 out of ~15-20 tests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this by removing and adding new PostbackTriggers at Page_init.